# What is a good place to post subjective/argumentitive programming questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, subjective

I did a [quick search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=subjective+argumentitive), but came up with no real helpful results.

Sometimes a subjective/argumentative question can be a helpful learning tool to help explore what others thing about certain subjects.  I've seen some pretty good "subjective" questions on StackOverflow get shut down pretty quick, even though the outcome of the discussion could have been really helpful.

So if we can't ask these questions on SO, is there a StackExchange site that will tolerate subjective/argumentative questions?

Comment: The "duplicate" answer recommends a place for subjective questions.  It does not answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development.

Check-out the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) though.

And you might want to read [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) as well.